# NextJS 13 and Redux - User Management

Tags: redux, next.js, react-redux, next.js13

I'm trying to migrate from `/page` directory to `/app` and I've stumble upon this problem with Redux.

I originally used Redux to store information about logged in user. It was fetched on client side. I have migrated this approach to `/app` but NextJS throws these errors:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.
Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "Stranger" Client: "User"
```

and

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: There was an error while hydrating this Suspense boundary. Switched to client rendering.
```

Can I ignore them? I know it's against the SSR style but I think that fetching user is better when done on client side. Otherwise I need to append auth cookies manually to the server request.

---

Also I'm using Redux Toolkit and it does work. I receive the user but the errors do occur.